# Jenkins AccessDeniedException upon trying to enable security on Jenkins on an EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-ec2

Last night when I was trying to set up Jenkins, from the jenkins.war file, I was trying to enable security, via username/password for it. I clicked the "Disable read access to anonymous" checkbox, and right after doing that, I got this screen [image], even after logging in with the new credentials I just created. I have tried the following (which has resulted in this screen still):

- removing anything on the EC2 that had to deal with Jenkins (`sudo find / -name "*jenkins*"` followed by `sudo rm [-rf]` on anything that popped up in the results)
- re-visiting that site after doing the above option
- re-installing the WAR file
- installing Jenkins as a service
- attempting login again

Is there a way out of this?

Answer (score 0):

I should have checked the processes and `kill`ed the one that was Jenkins. The process somehow outlived its JAR/WAR executable!